# Access Foreign Tables CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am sorry if the title is a bit confusing, I just don't know how this is properly called. I have a table structure like this for my CakePHP project.

**users** id, name, surname, userrecords

**userrecords**  id, user_id, records_id

**records** id, description

I understand that to access the **userrecords** middle table in my **users view** I have to do something like

```
$user['userrecords']['id'];
```

How can I neatly access **description** in **records** table through a **users view**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify whether you're using CakePHP 2.x or 3.x, so I provided solutions for both.

The relationship you are referring to is called a **"Has And Belongs To Many"** relationship.  Since both of your model are associated to a linking table (userrecords), you can freely associate as many records to as many users as you want.

First, I would consider renaming your 'userrecords' table to 'users_records' to play nicely with CakePHP.

First, define your relationship within your Users model:

```
// Using CakePHP 2.x:
class User extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable'); // Instantiate Containable behavior
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Record' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Record',
                'joinTable' => 'users_records',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'record_id'
            )
    );
}

// Using CakePHP 3.x:
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize (array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Records', [
            'joinTable' => 'users_records' // Defines our linking table
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, we must define our relationship within our Records model:

```
// Using CakePHP 2.x:
class Record extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable'); // Instantiate Containable behavior
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'joinTable' => 'users_records',
                'foreignKey' => 'record_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
            )
    );
}

// Using CakePHP 3.x:
class RecordsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize (array $config) 
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'joinTable' => 'users_records' // Defines our linking table
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, we can access the associated records freely from each model using the ORM's contain method:

```
// Using CakePHP 2.x:
// Getting 'User' and associated 'Record' models in Controller:
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->find('all', array('contain' => 'Record'));

// Getting 'Record' and associated 'User' models in Controller:
$this->loadModel('Record');
$this->Record->find('all', array('contain' => 'User'));

// Using CakePHP 3.x:
// Getting 'User' and associated 'Record' models:
$users_table = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$users = $users_table->find()->contain('Records')->all();

// Getting 'Record' and associated 'User' models:
$records_table = TableRegistry::get('Records');
$records = $records_table->find()->contain('Users')->all();
```

Read the Cookbook, it will make your life a million times easier:

[CakePHP 2.x Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

[CakePHP 2.x Has And Belongs To Many Relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)

[CakePHP 3.x belongsToMany Relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations)

[CakePHP 3.x Retrieving Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data)

[CakePHP 3.x Eager Loading Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations)

Answer (score 1):

Read this,this may be helpful for you

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Answer (score 0):

Because your table structure as below :

User -> UserRecord -> Record

So that you can only get [Record]  via [UserRecord]

You should set recursive property in find command.

Please refer for more information about recursive at this link : [what is the meaning of recursive in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381334/what-is-the-meaning-of-recursive-in-cakephp)

I hope this answer doesn't misunderstand your question.